# How to set line as a background using xml (shape) below to EditText?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I want to set the line as background below EditText using shape xml but when I set it line set on center

I want like below

[image]

but when I set the shape below

drawable/line.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:shape="line" >
> <stroke
>     android:height="4dp"
>     android:color="@color/crabfx_dark_gray" />
> </shape>
> ```

activity_main.xml

> ```
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/edt"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>     android:layout_margin="20dp" 
>     android:background="@drawable/line"/>
> ```

I got below output

[image]

is any solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one i hope you will get perfect solution..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Or Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="1px"
    android:left="0px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want this solution, I need shape

Answer (score -1):

Try this code just below your EDIT_text:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/dividerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#191919"
     >
</View>
```