# Customize the design for EditText in android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have tried with some solution over the problem that I have but fail to get the expected design for `EditText` in android.

[image]

The Final Design should look like this. It has the light gray color border at the bottom and on focus it should change the color to something else.

All the suggestions and solutions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Add <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color_code</item> in your app them style

Comment: check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203292/how-to-set-line-as-a-background-using-xml-shape-below-to-edittext

Comment: use this may it help you https://github.com/wrapp/floatlabelededittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="1px"
    android:left="0px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: it's not working, Any additional thins are there might be I have missed?

Comment: you have add this xml as background of your edit text??

Comment: I have made cleaned and build and its working now! Don't know what exactly was the issue! Thanks @Krishna

Answer (score 0):

I think so this is your point:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">    

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: design doesn't rendered due to `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout ....>`

Comment: @iSandeep are you add compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' to your gradle?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `styles` try adding below lines of code to your activity's `style` or `theme`

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yourNormalColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yourActiveColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourHighlightColor</item>
```

Comment: it's not working, Any additional thins are there might be I have missed?

Comment: How you have done it?, can you post your code.@iSandeep

Comment: Here is my style.xml`<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- theme customizations -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yourNormalColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yourActiveColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourHighlightColor</item>
    </style></resources>`

Comment: did you put this in your manifest for particular activity? and try putting this in styles-v21 as well, and put some colors also if u haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `drawable` as horizontal line (extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555379/3027124)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And set the background to `EditText` in xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:text="User Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/horizonal_line"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:text="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/horizonal_line"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.